# How can I start a UiPath Robot from Groovy scripting language?

Tags: rest, groovy, rpa, uipath

How can I start a UiPath Robot from Groovy scripting language?

I have my process on UiPath Orchestrator and I want to send a set of REST API commands to the UiPath Orchestrator from Groovy to start the process.

I have read the [Orchestrator documentation](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/authenticating), but I was not able to create a working script.

The main idea for this is that after more study different software like for example Jira or Jenkins uses this Groovy language for scripting.

Comment: You can start UiPath process via API. Do you mean this? And please write some more about your issue.

Comment: Yes, we talk about starting the Robot via REST API. For each scripting system, there are different tips and tricks little stuff, and from my point of view is very useful for the end-user to find exactly the code that was working in the movie.

Comment: Using SO for adverting is not a good thing. Hopefully you just use SO for really asking questions in the future my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a Groovy script code that starts UiPath Process on the UiPath Orchestrator:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder();
def root = builder{
                    grant_type 'refresh_token'
                    client_id 'YOUR CLIENT ID'
                    refresh_token 'YOUR REFRESH TOKEN'
                 }
assert root instanceof Map

def link = new URL("https://account.uipath.com/oauth/token");
def connection = link.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection;

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-UIPATH-TenantName","YOUR TENANTNAME");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

def httpRequestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()))
httpRequestBodyWriter.write(builder)
httpRequestBodyWriter.close()
def auth = "0"
if(connection.responseCode == 200)
{
    def resp = connection.inputStream.text
    auth = resp.substring(resp.indexOf("access_token")+15,resp.indexOf("id_token")-3)    
    println resp
}

def builder2 = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder();
//process without parameters
/*def root2 = builder2.startInfo {
                    ReleaseKey 'YOUR PROCESS ReleaseKey'
                    Strategy 'All'
                 }*/
//process with parameters
def root2 = builder2.startInfo {
                    ReleaseKey 'YOUR PROCESS ReleaseKey'
                    Strategy 'All'
                    InputArguments '{"param1":"Test Youtube","param2":"GroovyConsole"}'
                 }
assert root2 instanceof Map

def link2 = new URL("https://platform.uipath.com/[Account Logical Name]/[Tenant Logical Name]/odata/Jobs/UiPath.Server.Configuration.OData.StartJobs");
def connection2 = link2.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection;

connection2.setRequestProperty("Authorization",'Bearer '+auth);
connection2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
connection2.setRequestProperty("X-UIPATH-TenantName","YOUR TENANTNAME");
connection2.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","telnet");
connection2.setDoOutput(true);

def httpRequestBodyWriter2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection2.getOutputStream()))
httpRequestBodyWriter2.write(builder2)
httpRequestBodyWriter2.close()

   println connection2.responseCode
   println connection2.responseMessage
```

Comment: Hello All, sorry to create so many issues. My idea is to share a small script that is working and for this, I give a link of Youtube video to demonstrate that it is working.  I don't want to promote, I just share code that was done inside of Salesforce, ServiceNow, NetSuite, JS, Groovy ...  not UiPath. This idea comes from a simple fact that in the past I watch many tutorials on YouTube and when I want to try what was there I need to rewrite the code.  In this way people that watch videos can test code very easy. My post are community wiki. I need to remove links to youtube from my answers?

Comment: Done, I modify the question and the answer to be totally independent of Youtube. This can be useful for anyone that wants to use REST API commands from Groovy.